# How do I play a .wav from BRAVE with UBUNTU?

Tags: sound

How do I play a .wav from BRAVE with UBUNTU?

The best I can come up with is a command line option.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by playing file from the browser. Once you download it you can play it with vlc

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. I have Brave Browser installed in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and without any modifications to Brave, every .WAV file from https://www.winhistory.de/more/winstart/winstart_en.htm plays just fine without the need to download.  There was never a need to use the command line.  So I am lost as to what you are actually asking.  Please modify your question and give errors or examples, even screenshots, of what is not working for you.

Comment: 10 PM Sat and I just discovered .wav downloaded from Yahoo Mail on UBUNTU are only 385 bytes. Same downloaded from Windows 34K+ bytes. Seems the problem is in the download in Yahoo Mail in BRAVE. I'll try a diffeent browser tomorrow. Thank to all for responses.

Comment: Mia culpa - It turns out the attached .wav on my Yahoo Mail msg was bad. Emailed myself with a goo .wav and it works fine. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: With the above comment question closed as non-reproducible...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I have seen this in a couple of places, and it always confuses me: why do you think UBUNTU and BRAVE are acronyms and what do you think they stand for? Is there any website out there telling people that UBUNTU is an acronym?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Capitalization does not imply it's an acronym. If you've been on Twitter or Reddit, there's this annoying trend of capitalizing nouns for emphasis, usually for contrast: Our COMPETITION amd makes their cpus with sand GLUEd together (chiplets). OUR new phones are made of TITANIUM (iPhone 15).

Answer (score 1):

Install all the codecs with `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Then install `vlc` with `sudo apt install vlc`

Double click the .wav file to run it with vlc.

Comment: Audacious is easier to use than VLC and it also supports importing a music library. You can install Audacious in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with `sudo apt install audacious`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to install any new software like vlc, audacious, or codecs.

Simply open a new tab in Brave or Firefox, and drag the `.wav` file into it. The file will start playing automatically. Browsers have their own bundled versions of codecs that cover most cases.